# Unexpected Element : CDATA while validating response

Tags: json, xml, validation, soap, cdata

please find below my json response

```
{"birthday": "1991-09-09","familyName": "abcdefgh", "profiles": [], "title": "Mr","id": 123456,"middleName": null,"emailVerified": "2016-01-27 15:45:03 +0000", "primaryAddress": {"company": null, "address2": null,"stateAbbreviation": null,"zipPlus4": null,"city": null,"address1": null,"phone": null,  "zip": null,"mobile": null,"country": null},"gender": null,"lastUpdated": "2016-02-22 05:31:30.678332 +0000","assignedRoles":[{"relatedManagedObject": "/abcdefgh/abcdefgh/123456789","roleType": "EndUser","createdDateTime": "2014-03-07 15:43:00 +0000","managedObject": "/abcdefgh/subscribers/44123456789","id": 11010,"label": "44123456789","endDate": null},{"roleType": "LegalOwner","createdDateTime": "2016-03-07 15:43:00 +0000","managedObject": "/abcdefgh/abcdefgh/123456789","id": 11010,"label": "123456789","endDate": null}],"password": null,"photos": [],"email": "abcd.in","givenName": "abcd","currentLocation": null,"deactivateAccount": null,"lastLogin": null,"created": "2016-02-24 19:18:54.415972 +0000","displayName": null,"uuid": "fgisdufuidsfgrughkurhgkufhghfughdfklh","aboutMe": null,"display": null,"statuses": []}
```

Whenever i try to validate in SOAP i get validation error as **unexpected element : CDATA**

Could you please guide on this

Answer (score 0):

Your json formatting is wrong.. If you paste your response to jsonlint.com, you'll see that..

For example,

```
birthday: 1991 - 09 - 09,
familyName: abcdefg
```

should be:

```
"birthday": "1991-09-09",
"familyName": "abcdefg"
```

notice the quotes. so re-format your json and see what happens

Comment: Hi

Please find the updated code,
my bad that i didnt not upload it on stack properly.
Thanks for pointing it out, however i am still facing the same problem

Comment: your updated json is valid.. so the problem is not with this string at all. Can you post other related code?

Comment: This is the only response that i have.

Comment: OK but you must get this error either when parsing or sending it right?

Comment: nop
i just try to validate it in SOAP, so when i right click and validate it i get the error